# Django extends not working

Tags: python, html, django

I have a problem with execute html view. I have base.html which do not showing the child views from another files. Can anybody help me what I doing wrong? Here are my files:
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Kategorie(models.Model):
    glowna = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Kategoria')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural='Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.glowna


class Witryna(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Nazwa strony')
    adres_www = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Adres www')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Przyjazny adres url')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Adres e-mail')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name='Opis strony')
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    data_publikacji = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data publikacji')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def publikacja(self):
        self.data_publikacji=timezone.now()
        self.save()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^strony$', views.widok_strony, name='widok_strony'),
    url(r'^$', views.widok_kategorii, name='widok_kategorii'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Witryna, Kategorie
from django.utils import timezone
#from django.db.models import Count


def widok_strony(request):
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_strony.html', {'firmy': firmy})

def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all()
    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html', {'kategorie': kategorie, 'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat})
```

**widok_kategorii.html**

```
{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block kategorie %}


{%  for kategoria in kategorie %}

<table>
<tr>
<th>
<a href="#">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a>({{ wpisy_kat }}) 
</th>
</tr>
</table>
{%  endfor %}
{% endblock kategorie%}
```

**widok_strony.html**

```
{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block firmy %}


{%  for firma in firmy %}
<div>
<img src="http://free.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=s&url={{ firma.adres_www }}"/> 
<a href="">{{ firma.nazwa }}</a><p>
</div>
{%  endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% include 'firmy/header.html' %}
<html>
<body>
<h4>Ostatnio dodane</h4>
{% block firmy %}

{% endblock %}
<h4>Kategorie</h4>
{% block kategorie %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
{% include 'firmy/footer.html' %}
</html>
```

When I try to run localhost:8000 the base.html showing me only the view from widok_kategorii.html file.Of course when I change the url to localhost:8000/strony that page is loading perfectly. But I want to have this two html files on the one page base.html

Comment: Do you want to show the two html files on one page (widok_strony.html & widok_kategorie.html) ?

Comment: you might not have any `Kategorie` objects.

Comment: Saschin yes it is. I want to show two html files on one page

Comment: I have 56 records in Kategorie

Comment: But these are two separate URLs, two separate views, and two separate templates. They can't be shown on the same page.

Comment: Right now, both your files are separated and are being rendered in different views. You need to make one template file, where you extend the base and include the other two templates. Help: `{% include 'widok_strony.html' %}` in the appropriate block, likewise the other file in the other block.

Comment: instead of {% endblock kategorie%} please use only {% endblock %}

Comment: Daniel so how can I solve this? I can use {% block %} only once ?

Comment: Sachin so for example I have to create index.html, extends base.html and include in index.html two files: widok_strony.html & widok_kategorie.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming your blocks so that they do not overlap with the names of arguments you are passing through view.py.

I would try the following:

**widok_kategorii.html**

```
{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block content_kat %}
{% for kategoria in kategorie %}

<table>
<tr>
<th>
<a href="#">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a>({{ wpisy_kat }}) 
</th>
</tr>
</table>
{%  endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**widok_strony.html**

```
{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block content_firm %}

{%  for firma in firmy %}
<div>
<img src="http://free.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=s&url={{ firma.adres_www }}"/> 
<a href="">{{ firma.nazwa }}</a><p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% include 'firmy/header.html' %}
<html>
<body>
<h4>Ostatnio dodane</h4>
{% block content_firm %}
{% endblock %}
<h4>Kategorie</h4>
{% block content_kat %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
{% include 'firmy/footer.html' %}
</html>
```

Realize that you will not get both content on the same page at one instance. If you would like to have both content on the same page then you need to combine the views and htmls.

I would do the following:

**views.py**

```
def widok_strony_kategorii(request):
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all()
    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_strony_kategorii.html', {'firmy': firmy,'kategorie': kategorie, 'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat})
```

**firmy/widok_strony_kategorii.html**

```
{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block content_kat %}
{% for kategoria in kategorie %}

<table>
<tr>
<th>
<a href="#">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a>({{ wpisy_kat }}) 
</th>
</tr>
</table>
{%  endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block content_firm %}

{%  for firma in firmy %}
<div>
<img src="http://free.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=s&url={{ firma.adres_www }}"/> 
<a href="">{{ firma.nazwa }}</a><p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**firmy/base.html**

```
<<Same as the edited one above>>
```

Comment: Thank You very much Jasol. I will try this solution. What do You think about urls.py? In this case I'am obligated to change the urlpattern or leave it like this: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^strony$', views.widok_strony, name='widok_strony'),
    url(r'^$', views.widok_kategorii, name='widok_kategorii'),
]

Comment: If you are going to combine the two views together into function widok_strony_kategorii, then you would need to change the urls.py as well (forgot to add to my post). urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.widok_strony_kategorii,name='widok_strony_kategorii')
]